# Reloading postgreSQL without breaking current connection?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, redhat

I was wondering if i issued a reload command to Postgres so that it could reread the pg_hba.conf file (Made some changes in here and need them to take immediate effect on a live system) will destroy or drop and current connections?

/etc/init.d/postgreSQL83 reload

Comment: On a side note, 8.3 is unsupported and you should look at upgrading. http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: Thanks Craig. I will definitely note that.

Answer (score 7):

I crossed my fingers and tried this on my own. And, it worked! No connections dropped. So you can actually issue a     postgreSQL reload command at the command prompt and it only reads the configuration file. It does not restart the PostgreSQL server nor drop connections.

Comment: Correct, `pg_ctl reload` doesn't break connections. A restart will.

Comment: And it reads all conf files, (eg `pg_hba.conf` as well), not just `postgresql.conf`.